# Dynamically shows Crystal Report group footer

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I need to do something specific in Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2005.

Let's say the following data:
[image]

The report regroup the data with the prdCode field, which gives something like this:
[image]

Now, I need to add a subtotal everytime one of the 4 first columns changes (Lot / Cédule/ Brand/ Contenant in the report). In this case, I should have a subtotal for the first row (lot=153363 and next one is 171008). Then, another subtotal at the last line of lot=171008 and Cédule = 023854. Then another subtotal at lot=171008 and cédule = 023863, etc.

I have no idea how I can do this. Adding Groups won't help, as I will have 5 group footers display for the first row only. In the case of the above image, I should display only 5 subtotals. A subtotal is the sum of the Total Gross/Tare/Net fields.

Anyone can help me out on this?

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct adding 5 groups doesn't solve the issue and also it doesn't make any sense, Instead combine all your fields and create a single group that will seggregate the records as required.

Try following approach.

Create a formula `@grouping` and write below cide

```
ToText(Lot)&ToText(Cédule)&Brand&Contenant
```

Now create a group with this formula and take summary in group footer

Comment: wow, you're a genius!!! it works perfectly!!! thanks a million times for your answer! :-)